# python - read document and modify what i want to change

Tags: python

I am trying to modify document text using python.

this is the document text as follow :

```
abcdefghijklmn
<entry colname="1" rowname="1">a</entry>
<entry morecols="5" morecolname="2" namest="2" nameend="7" rowname="1">a</entry>
<entry colname="1" morerows="9" morerowname="2">b</entry>
<entry morecols="5" morecolname="2" namest="2" nameend="7" rowname="2">b</entry>
<entry colname="1" morerows="9" morerowname="2">b</entry>
<morecols="4" morecolname="3" namest="3" nameend="7" morerows="2" morerowname="3">c</entry>
<entry colname="2" rowname="3">c</entry>
<entry colname="2" rowname="4">d</entry>
<entry morecols="1" morecolname="2" namest="2" nameend="3" morerows="2" morerowname="5">e</entry>
<entry colname="2" rowname="5">e</entry>
abcdefghijklmn
```

I'd like to add `TEST` at the every end of sentence that contains the last `rowname="n"` (including `morerowname="n"`)

So this is result i want below

```
abcdefghijklmn
<entry colname="1" rowname="1">a</entry>
<entry morecols="5" morecolname="2" namest="2" nameend="7" rowname="1">a</entry>TEST
<entry colname="1" morerows="9" morerowname="2">b</entry>
<entry morecols="5" morecolname="2" namest="2" nameend="7" rowname="2">b</entry>
<entry colname="1" morerows="9" morerowname="2">b</entry>TEST
<morecols="4" morecolname="3" namest="3" nameend="7" morerows="2" morerowname="3">c</entry>
<entry colname="2" rowname="3">c</entry>TEST
<entry colname="2" rowname="4">d</entry>TEST
<entry morecols="1" morecolname="2" namest="2" nameend="3" morerows="2" morerowname="5">e</entry>
<entry colname="2" rowname="5">e</entry>TEST
abcdefghijklmn
```

and this is code i'm trying so far but i don't know how to code the if option

```
with open("C:\\TEST\\test_addrow.xml","r",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = f.read()

result = list()
All_text = data.split("\n")

a = 1
find_text = 'rowname="{}".*'.format(a)

for t in All_text:
    if re.search(find_text, data) :
       re.findall(find_text, data)[-1]
       result.append(t+"TEST")
    a = a + 1
    else:
        result.append(t)

with open("C:\\TEST\\test_addrow.xml","w",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(result))
```

Would you give me any advice?
Thanks

Comment: A couple problems: there's a mistake in this line: `if re.search(find_text, data) :`;
you're not doing anything with the result of `re.findall(find_text, data)[-1]`; your code would add TEST to the first line that contains a new number, not the last

Comment: Taking a variable to know the last number found. If the current number is different, add `"TEST"` to end of line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you can just make some manipulation's to what you're splitting on... the logic is still the same:

Input:

```
$cat test_addrow.xml
<entry colname="1" rowname="1">a</entry>
<entry morecols="5" morecolname="2" namest="2" nameend="7" rowname="1">a</entry>
<entry colname="1" morerows="9" morerowname="2">b</entry>
<entry morecols="5" morecolname="2" namest="2" nameend="7" rowname="2">b</entry>
<entry colname="1" morerows="9" morerowname="2">b</entry>
<morecols="4" morecolname="3" namest="3" nameend="7" morerows="2" morerowname="3">c</entry>
<entry colname="2" rowname="3">c</entry>
<entry colname="2" rowname="4">d</entry>
<entry morecols="1" morecolname="2" namest="2" nameend="3" morerows="2" morerowname="5">e</entry>
<entry colname="2" rowname="5">e</entry>
```

Code:

```
with open('test_addrow.xml') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    with open('test_addrow.xml', 'w') as file1:
        for i, line in enumerate(lines[:-1]):
            current_n = int(line.split('rowname="')[-1].split('"')[0])
            next_n = int(lines[i+1].split('rowname="')[-1].split('"')[0])
            if next_n != current_n:
                file1.write(line.strip() + "TEST\n")
            else:
                file1.write(line)
        # Write the last line which always has TEST appended
        file1.write(lines[-1].strip() + "TEST\n")
```

Output:

```
$cat test_addrow.xml
<entry colname="1" rowname="1">a</entry>
<entry morecols="5" morecolname="2" namest="2" nameend="7" rowname="1">a</entry>TEST
<entry colname="1" morerows="9" morerowname="2">b</entry>
<entry morecols="5" morecolname="2" namest="2" nameend="7" rowname="2">b</entry>
<entry colname="1" morerows="9" morerowname="2">b</entry>TEST
<morecols="4" morecolname="3" namest="3" nameend="7" morerows="2" morerowname="3">c</entry>
<entry colname="2" rowname="3">c</entry>TEST
<entry colname="2" rowname="4">d</entry>TEST
<entry morecols="1" morecolname="2" namest="2" nameend="3" morerows="2" morerowname="5">e</entry>
<entry colname="2" rowname="5">e</entry>TEST
```

Comment: I'm sorry . I changed the text to make this more clear

Comment: Have one more question. what if there are general texts in the example document ? it shows error.

Comment: if there is abcdefg above <entry colname="1" rowname="1">a</entry> (the first line) this shows error

Comment: You could add `if 'rowname' in line:` right after the for loop. Or do a try: except: block

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code.

> Use of the `split()` method defined on strings is also a good choice in this case. Regular expression is also good as you've used in your code.
>
> Try it online at http://rextester.com/HOLRV63641

```
import re

# Reading XML file 
with open("C:\\TEST\\test_addrow.xml", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

last_num = ""  # It is to store the value of rowname & morerowname attributes
last_index = 0 # It is to store the last index matched for line which has rowname and morerowname attibutes
opened = False # It is to track he first and last match found for sequence of same numbers

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    arr = re.findall(r"rowname=\"\d+", line)
    arr2 = []
    if arr:
        arr2 = arr[0].split('"')

    if arr2:
        if last_num and last_num != arr2[1]:
            lines[last_index] = lines[last_index].strip() + 'TEST' + '\n'
            opened = False # Added TEST so close
        else:
            opened = True  # Continue as the number is matched

        last_index = i
        last_num = arr2[1]
    else:
        if last_index:
            lines[last_index] = lines[last_index].strip() + 'TEST' + '\n'
            opened = False # Added TEST so close

# In cases like if the XML file only has 1 line
if opened:
    lines[last_index] = lines[last_index].strip() + 'TEST' + '\n'

lines = "".join(lines)

# Writing modified lines to file
with open("C:\\TEST\\test_addrow.xml", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(lines)
```

Comment: Actually, this isn't the full text and that doesn't work if there are more numbers in example text

Comment: **@Cho**, have you tried it, please modify the example available online and see the output. I checked, it works.

Comment: **@Cho**, you can visit at http://rextester.com/SDNNZE75313 and see the output. Just run the example. You can modify also. Please do let me know if still it fails.

Comment: I'm sorry hygull . I changed the text to make this more clear

Comment: No problem, I will let you know once I modify the code.

Comment: Do you expect the same output which you have mentioned?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176498/discussion-between-hygull-and-cho).

Comment: **@Cho**, I've updated my answer. You can have a look.